# Why are we getting “The path is not of a legal form” for a FileInfo constructor?

Tags: c#, fileinfo

We're creating a FileInfo object in C# using the following code:

```
if (planConfig->OrganisationsFilePath != nullptr)
{
   FileInfo^ file = gcnew FileInfo(planConfig->OrganisationsFilePath);
   //Do some stuff here
}
```

and our customers are reporting that they see an ArgumentException with “The path is not of a legal form” as the message being thrown. We cannot reproduce this and we're wondering what string you'd need to pass to the FileInfo constructor to see this error?

Comment: Any random junk would throw that exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The path probably contains invalid characters. See the [MSDN documentation on FileInfo constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.fileinfo.aspx).

> ArgumentException:The file name is empty, contains only white spaces, or contains invalid  characters.